# TypeScript Vue.js Component Type Never

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I have a Vue.js component with a property that I declared as follows:

```
props: {
  modelValue: {
    type: [Object, null] as PropType<Filter | null>,
    default: null,
    required: true,
  },
}
```

When I use the component with an instantiated `Filter object`, I get the following error:

```
Argument of type '{ modelValue: ...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

The error is displayed in the VSCode editor, I think it is reported by eslint.
How can I resolve this error?

I call my component like this

```
<filter v-model="myFilter" />
```

```
setup() {
    const myFilter = ref<Filter | null>(null);
}
```

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. It's unknown what you do to cause this error

Comment: @FrançoisSchuster, Where is the error? Here is the working reproduction. [Reproduction: Vue SFC Playground with TypeScript](https://shorturl.at/hBEO6)

Comment: The error is displayed in the VSCode editor, I think it is reported by eslint.

Comment: Such an error message should come from TypeScript, but since you haven't shared the specific reproducible code, it's difficult to determine the exact cause of the error. One can only guess. Most likely, the type of the variable passed to v-model cannot be inferred. For example, you might be passing a generic type variable, or the object you're passing might initially be an empty object {} without a specified type. Consequently, it would propagate as an empty object type, resulting in "never," since it will never be of type Filter or null.

Comment: I added my calling code to the component but I don't see what's wrong.
I tried to do the same on play.vuejs.org.
Could this be a configuration problem?

Comment: In the setup() method of the Options API, it's not sufficient to just declare the variable. At the end, it must return with the variables passed to the template. In this case, it should return like this: `return { myFilter }`